# How to load NIB interfaces as the home screen for my app instead of the storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, xib

I have two story boards. One for Arabic UI another for English UI.

I have one Start screen that have two buttons, Arabic - English

Based on users decision, I want to load the appropriate UI storyboard.

I have created StartScreen.xib, and selected it as the Main Interface in the Project Target -> Deployment Info.

But when I run my app, I got blank black screen.

How can I set xib file as the home screen for my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should put this code in your AppDelegate to display your first screen with the 2 buttons :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window.rootViewController = [[CustomViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CustomViewController" bundle:nil];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

And then on tap on button load the corresponding storyboard and instiantiate its `initialViewController` with something like :

```
UIStoryboard*sb = [UIStoryboard storybardWithName:@"storyEN" bundle:nil]; 
self.view.window.rootViewController = [sb instantiateInitialViewController];
```

Sorry for eventual mistakes, I have no Mac to tests for the moment :).

Either way, have you thought about localizing your storyboard to implement such behaviour ? Or the layout of your views are too different to make it work between both languages within a single storyboard ?

**EDIT :**

The swift version of above code :

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary?) -> Bool {

    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

    self.window.rootViewController = CustomViewController ( nibName:"CustomViewController", bundle: nil)

    self.window.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}
```

And the second block :

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "storyEN", bundle: nil);
let vc = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController as UIViewController;
self.view.window.rootViewController = vc;
```

**EDIT #2**

For the exception you're having, it seems that the view is not blinded to the file's owner, which cause the exception you get.
Check in your Interface Builder that you have :

[image: Interface Builder]

Comment: But do you speak Swift language?

Comment: Yes sorry... let me edit my answer to 'translate' it toSwift language :)

Comment: I have localized my Storyboard but I have a requirement that the user should be able to switch languages without changing devices language and without closing and reopening the app. So I recreated two storyboard to solve this requirement.

Comment: I've added a screenshot to help you check everything is OK. If you still encounter some problems try create a new Nib from scratch (File->New File->User Interface->View) and recreate your view, it should work